# transpose a list of lists clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a transpose function that works for fixed arities

```
(defn transpose [a b c]
  (map list a b c))

(transpose '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))
((1 4 7) (2 5 8) (3 6 9))

(apply transpose (list '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9)))
((1 4 7) (2 5 8) (3 6 9))
```

But how can I generalise this for n arguments so I could call it as follows:

```
(transpose '(1 2) '(4 5))
(transpose '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))
...
```

I feel as thought I need something like the following

```
(defn transpose [& xs]
  (apply (map list) xs))
```

But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close:

```
(defn transpose [& xs]
  (apply map list xs))
```